# href link with target blank at specific position

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html pages.

```
1. main page (it has all the links like a b c d )
2. details page (it has all the details of a b c d)
```

like this

when user clicks on link a it redirects in new window to `details.html`
it is working fine.

but the problem is when user clicks on link `'d'`. it also redirects to `details.html` but `d`link details are somewhere at the bottom of page and user have to scroll it to fine d.

i want to do the automatic positioning of `details.html` like if d link is clicked it should get to `details.html` in new window. and displaying d at the top of page. see user don't have to scroll it manually.

Any possible Solution. I don't know what should i write to google it. Thanks

Comment: Add a id to div wrapping link and scroll to that id on page load.

Comment: @vjdhama in details page?

Comment: Yep you can scroll using javascript to a div with id on page load.

Comment: @vjdhama i got it. so what are you saying is, i should pass an id to next page and get that id in js and scroll according to the passed value/id on page load. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an ID, and a `#` in the URL to do what you want.

Given a details page that looks something like this:

```
<div id="a">
<h1>Details about A</h1>
</div>

<div id="b">
<h1>Details about B</h1>
</div>

<div id="c">
<h1>Details about C</h1>
</div>

<div id="d">
<h1>Details about D</h1>
</div>
```

You would then link like such:

```
<a href="/details.html#d>Link to Details about D</a>
```

Basically, give an element an ID which, as always, represents what it contains

Link to it by putting that ID after the pound sign

```
<a herf="/LINK_TO_PAGE#ID_ON_PAGE">...
```

Comment: i didn't get you. can you explain it in more details.

Comment: That's about as detailed as it gets. Give an element an ID, and link to that ID by placing it in the URL, after a `#`. Try my example, by putting more text in each DIV. That might help.